# Search between 2 files in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: search, ide, find, visual-studio-2017

So I have recently switched from VS2010 (which just kept crashing at least every day) to VS Community 2017, and one of the things I used to do basically all the time, which is to select the name of a function/variable in one file, ctrl+F it then switch to a different file and search for it there, I just can't do anymore because of that stupid quicksearch bar.

However, the reflex to do that is so deeply ingrained by now, that I often end up opening the quick search in one file anyway, then switching file, then facepalming with a grunt as I go back to the previous file, ctrl+c, then back, then ctrl+f, ctrl+v, then enter. You can see how that can get frustrating with 20+ occurences a day. (yes, I swap-search through files a lot. It's how the projects I work on are designed, and it really worked just fine before they prevented me from doing that one very important little task quickly. Ugh!)

I have searched all around for a solution to this, but the common "Fix" is to map ctrl+F to the "search all files". It doesn't do what I need to do. If I switch the "search in" option back to "current document" (I know which file I'm looking into! I don't want to look through ALLL open files, or the entire project, just that one other file that's not the one I have open right this second), IT GOES BACK TO THE QUICK SEARCH BAR!!!

I can't be the only one with that search-switch file-find workflow. Is there an extension I missed that would fix this? Some kind of hacky registry modification that would give me back my good ol' search dialog without that annoying quick search? (Seriously, I had the power tools or whatever extension that had this in VS 2010, and had turned it off literally after the first time I used it cuz I **hated it**). Or! Hey, maybe something that'll at least keep that little box open/preserve the search value between files.

The time I spend having to go back and copy instead of right up search is making the switch to vs2017 almost irellevant vs the once a day crashing of vs 2010.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's wrong with Ctrl+Shift+F? That overlay stays open if you switch files. Restrict the search to open document and you're fine.

Comment: Then I have to constantly switch back and forth when I *do* need to search all files, and that's when it doesn't just shift the focus back to the quick search bar when I select "Current Document" (which was happening this morning when I made the post, but isn't doing it anymore, at least). To a certain degree, that's even more cumbersome than the ctrl+c/ctrl+tab/ctrl+f/ctrl+v workaround I got going. Guess I'll just hafta get used to it with time...